# Is it possible to delete/ignore all items on recursion/call stack, when I have hit a certain condition and simply return True to the overall function?

Tags: python, recursion

I am answering a question where we are given 3 strings: `one`, `two` and `three`. We want to return a Boolean to say whether we can create `string three` by **interweaving** strings `one` and `two`.

For example:

```
one = "aab", two = "aac", three = "aaab" -> this should return True
```

Whereas

```
one = "abb", two = "acc", three = "aaab" -> this should return False
```

My approach is two simply create `three pointers` pointing at the start of the three strings. And increment them one by one, when we find a match between strings `one and three` or `two and three`.

The above becomes tricky when `pointer_one` and `pointer_two` point to the same character in `one` and `two` respectively! In this case, we need to run a `recursion`.
Now my question is when we start adding recursion calls to the `recursive stack`. We may get to a point where we **reach the end of** `string three`, and can `return True` for the **overall function**.

HOWEVER, there are still (partially complete) recursive calls in our recursion stack! And so the this latest `return True`, will be passed back to the previous caller, but I want to just `return True` for the whole function and ignore the remaining items in the recursion stack- is there anyway to do this?

Or would I have to write code in such a way as to simply `return` nothing until the stack is empty, and then `return True` to the final call?

The code I have written is quite long so I have omitted it for now but I can include it if necessary.

Thanks!

**My code:**

```
def interweavingStrings(one, two, three, pointer_one=0, pointer_two=0, pointer_three=0):
    possible_interwoven = False

    while pointer_three < len(three):

        if one[pointer_one] == two[pointer_two]:
            possible_interwoven = interweavingStrings(one, two, three, pointer_one + 1, pointer_two, pointer_three + 1)

            if not possible_interwoven:
                possible_interwoven = interweavingStrings(one, two, three, pointer_one, pointer_two + 1,
                                                          pointer_three + 1)

            if not possible_interwoven:
                break

        if pointer_two <= len(two) - 1 and three[pointer_three] == two[pointer_two]:
            pointer_two += 1
            pointer_three += 1
            possible_interwoven = True

        if pointer_one <= len(one) - 1 and three[pointer_three] == one[pointer_one]:
            pointer_one += 1
            pointer_three += 1
            possible_interwoven = True

        if pointer_two <= len(two) - 1 and pointer_one <= len(one) - 1 and one[pointer_one] != three[pointer_three] and two[pointer_two] != two[pointer_two]:
            return False

    return possible_interwoven
```

Comment: To answer your question literally - you can write your recursive function so that if one of the recursive calls returns True, then it should return True as well; however, you can't literally "shorten" the evaluation by "erasing the recursive calls on the call stack"; this would basically be tail-recursion optimization, which is supported by most programming languages but not by python.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether `one = "aaxb", two = "aaxc", three = "aaab"` should return True or False?

Comment: Hi Stef, thanks for the first comment I didn't think it would be possible to shorten the recursive stack, but I do see your point about returning True all the way- I think I now know how to do it. To your second commend, it should return False, since whether we pick the two a's in one or two, and one 'a' in the other, we can never reach 'b'.

Comment: However if you are interested about "shortening the stack" in a language other than python, I strongly recommend reading about tail-recursion.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stef, but I did read on Leetcode that tail recursion is possible in Python too?

Comment: No, tail-recursion is not possible in python. You can always write code that looks like it's tail-recursive, but no python interpreter will optimise the tail-recursion so it will always be basic recursion.

Comment: I see, okay that makes sense. I will check it out in Java, as this is the other language I am semi-proficient in coding in! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be part of your recursive function's structure.  When you make the recursive call, if it returns True, return from the current call with a value of True.

For example:

```
def canweave(a,b,c):
    if not c : return True
    if len(a)+len(b)<len(c): return False 
    if a and a[0]==c[0] and canweave(a[1:],b,c[1:]):
        return True                                   # works with 1st of a
    if b and b[0]==c[0] and canweave(a,b[1:],c[1:]):
        return True                                   # works with 1st of b
    return canweave(a[1:],b[1:],c)    # try with other chars
                                      # return result from recursion

print(canweave("aab","aac","aaab")) # True
print(canweave("abb","acc","aaab")) # False
```

*Observations on your code*:

The result from `possible_interwoven = interweavingStrings(...)` should be definitive than just a possibility.  When you obtain True from that call, you must be certain that the rest of the characters are "interwevable". So you should return True immediately when `possible_interwoven` is True.  This will automatically trickle up the recursive call to produce the final result.

There are also issues with how you advance your pointers but I can't see an easy way to fix that with a simple tweak.

here's a revised version using your pointer approach:

```
def interweavingStrings(one, two, three, 
                        pointer_one=0, pointer_two=0, pointer_three=0):
    if pointer_three == len(three): 
        return True
    if pointer_one >= len(one) and pointer_two >= len(two): 
        return False
    if pointer_one < len(one) and one[pointer_one] == three[pointer_three]:
        if interweavingStrings(one,two,three,
                               pointer_one+1,pointer_two,pointer_three+1):
            return True
    if pointer_two < len(two) and two[pointer_two] == three[pointer_three]:
        if interweavingStrings(one,two,three, 
                               pointer_one,pointer_two+1,pointer_three+1):
            return True
    return interweavingStrings(one,two,three, 
                               pointer_one+1,pointer_two+1,pointer_three)
```

Comment: Thank Alain, your answer makes sense but I am not so used to substituting slices into the arguments of recursion- could you kindly check my code and see where it can be tweaked? Thanks!

Comment: Comparing it to yours at first sight, rather than incrementing the pointers in the way I have above, should I be introducing more recursive calls and incrementing them in the arguments?

Comment: Yes, that is typically how recursive functions are built. See the revised version of your code I added to the answer.

Comment: Note that `if x: return True; if y: return True; return z` can be shortened to `return x or y or z`

Comment: Also note it's dubious whether `canweave(a[1:],b[1:],c)` is allowed or not. For instance, what should be the result of `canweave('aaxb', 'aaxc', 'aaab')`? Your answer returns True, but when I read the OP's, question, my interpretation is that it should return False, although that's a bit ambiguous. Are we really allowed to discard these `'x'`?

Comment: In the OP's example, "c" is discarded on the True result so I assume that this would also apply to "x" or any other unused character.

Comment: As for the `return x or y or z` *shortening*, it would make a very complex looking condition in this case.  I went for clarity over conciseness.

Comment: I know that obviously, that's not my point.  I felt that saving a few characters/lines at the expense of clarity didn't bring any value and actually would make the answer more difficult to understand

Comment: That's a matter of taste, I suppose. Personally I find the `or` version much easier to understand than the `if` version.

Comment: The OP confirmed in comments that `canweave('aaxb', 'aaxc', 'aaab')` should return False.